# Is there a precedent or example for using a cardano NFT for permission verification?

Tags: plutus, nft

I would like to use ownership of a Cardano NFT as a requirement for editing an online document. i.e. if you own the nft then you will be capable of writing to the document,but if you do not own the required NFT then you will only be able to read.  Are there any examples of NFT ownership being used as a password of sorts like this?  any recommendations of where to start looking for a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you say is possible.

In [this repo](https://github.com/CardanoSevilla/cardano-summit-2021) you can find an example on how to mint an NFT and then use it to login to a web app.

I reckon you can use a similar approach for your use case.

Comment: Are you sure that you posted the link you intended?  I searched the repo and do not even see the word NFT appear

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Here you can find how to mint the NFTs: https://github.com/CardanoSevilla/cardano-summit-2021/tree/main/src/NFTs. The project uses GameChanger wallet to mint (https://gamechanger.finance). You can import those JSON in the Playground and mint your NFTs from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example: [SpaceBudz Contract](https://github.com/SpaceBudz/spacebudz/blob/main/src/cardano/market/contract.hs)
He created individual SpaceBudBid NFTs that basically mark the highest bid on-chain for a specific SpaceBud. That way he doesn't need to scan a lot of UTxOs and instead always keeps track of the highest bidder.

You can do the same thing by generating an NFT series for each document. The policy could be unlocked so that the owner of the document can grant an arbitrary number of people different rights (reading, writing, commenting etc.) which correlates to some action that mints a respective NFT for that user.